# Confusion about definition Petersson product

Tags: integration, number-theory, measure-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

I'm taking a course on modular forms, but my background in analysis is not that strong (I have taken complex analysis and measure theory before however). Therefore I'm a bit confused about the definition of the Petersson inner product.

Let $F$ be the usual fundamental domain for the SL$_2(\mathbb Z)$-action on the upper-half plane, then for cusp forms $f, g$ of weight $k$ we defined (with $z = x + iy$)
$$
\langle f, g \rangle = \int_F f(z) \overline{g(z)} y^k \frac{dx dy}{y^2}.
$$
One of the things I am confused by is putting the factor $1/y^2$ seperately. Why is this? If I instead write $\int_F f(z) \overline{g(z)} y^{k-2} dx dy,$ does this mean something else, or is this not a well-defined expression?

We also spoke about the "hyperbolic form", which as I understand it is the measure $\nu$ defined by
$$
\nu(S) = \int_S \frac{1}{y^2} dx dy.
$$
So, maybe what is meant is that we are integrating with respect to this measure, so $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_F f(z) \overline{g(z)} y^k d\nu(z)$. Is this something different from just integrating with respect to the Lebesgue measure and adding a factor $y^{-2}$?

Thanks in advance for any help and explainations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good, natural question. The point is that the measure $\mu(z) = \frac{dx dy}{y^2}$ is the unique (up to multiple) **Haar** measure here. This measure is invariant under the isometries of the upper half-plane, i.e. it's invariant under $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$. This makes it very natural for modular forms, as modular forms are also invariant under (subgroups of) $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$.

In particular, this is how you can be certain that $\int_F f(z) d\mu(z)$ is independent of the choice of fundamental domain $F$.

There is one more oddity that might come up later. When performing integrals, especially when interacting with Fourier expansions, it is sometimes natural to perform the $x$ integral first. This leaves $\frac{dy}{y^2}$. If the integration has led to the region $\int_0^\infty F(y) \frac{dy}{y^2}$ for some function $F$, then this is typically written $\int_0^\infty F(y)y^{-1} \frac{dy}{y}$. Why? Because now we're integrating over $\mathbb{R}^+$, which has Haar measure $dy/y$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has certainly helped me. Coming back to this answer after a bit more studying, I'm confused since I've only ever seen Haar measures defined for topological groups. So of what is the measure $\mu$ the Haar measure exactly? The upper-half plane is not a topological group, it is just a topological space with a $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$-action, and $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ is discrete, which means its Haar measure is the counting measure.

Comment: The upper halfplane is a topological group. It's isomorphic to $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{R}) /  \mathrm{SO}(2, \mathbb{R})$. In this sense, automorphic forms come from the double quotient $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z}) \backslash \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{R}) /  \mathrm{SO}(2, \mathbb{R})$. This is closely related to the "Iwasawa decomposition".

Comment: But $\mathrm{SO}(2, \mathbb R)$ is not a normal subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$.